# Let $T : U \to V$ be Linear and Onto Map such that $U$ is a $n$ dimensional vector space is the following claim true?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T : U \to V$ be Linear and Onto Map such that $U$ is a $n$ dimensional vector space then I need to prove\disprove following statement

$T$ is one one iff $\text{dim} V \gt \text{Nullity T}$

So, this is what I get :

$T$ is onto so,

$\text{Rank T} = \text{dim V}$

By rank nullity $\text{dim V} + \text{nullity T} =  n$

so,

$\text{dim V} = n - \text{nullity T}$ After this I am stuck , I have no idea how to proceed

Can anyone help me here ?

Comment: T is one one $\implies$ dim V > Nullity T but I am stuck on the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim is false, since $\;T\;$ is $\;1-1\;$ iff $\;T\;$ is an isomorphism (as it is given that $\;T\;$ is surjective), and this is then true iff $\;\dim V=\dim U=n\;$ . Counterexample

$$T:\Bbb R^4\to\Bbb R^3\;,\;\;T(x,y,z,w):=(x,y,z)$$

Then $\;T\;$ is clearly surjective and $\;\dim\Bbb R^3=3>1=\dim\ker T\;$, yet it can't be injective (why not?).

Comment: .$T$ is not injective because rank T $\le 3$ and using rank Nullity,ker T $\ge 1$

Comment: @sat091 ...or because injective linear transformation map lin. indep. sets to lin. indep. sts and thus they map something of the dimension $\;n\;$ to something od dimension $\;n\;$. Almost the same...